# How does one write to a parquet file only using fastparquet and in chunks?

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow, fastparquet

The `in chunks` is probably the hard part.

I need to write each small chunk, then upload to S3 and loop that.

I can't use AWS Wrangler, S3FS, or Pyarrow 2.0.0+ due to constraints of the codebase (most of my experiments fail as there are issues with pyarrow 2.0.0 on a new numpy version which i am also restricted to).

I can only use fastparquet and pandas.

Is there any way to write parquet in chunks in a for-loop using fastparquet?

Is doing this a reasonable option?

```
n_chunks = 10
merged_dataframes = np.array_split(df, n_chunks)
```

Comment: Does it need to be one file?  If so then what does "in chunks" mean?  Does it mean creating multiple row groups?  Can you use pyarrow 1.0.0?

Comment: No doesn't have to be one file, uploading one file at a time yes, from "chunking" the dataframe, but it can be multiple files.